# pipenv: package installed but module not found

Tags: python, cryptography, pipenv

I recently installed pipenv.
I need to use the module named Crypto under python 3.6. I currently run 3.8 so I decided to use pipenv !

`pipenv install Crypto`

```
Adding Crypto to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (da1a8d) out of date, updating to (ca72e7)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (da1a8d)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (da1a8d)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 9/9 —
```

Then I did :
`pipenv shell`
and 
`./skeleton.py init`

I got the message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./skeleton.py", line 5, in <module>
    from toolbox import *
  File "/home/alex/Documents/4TC-CSC/csc/td2-code/toolbox.py", line 11, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I don't understand what is wrong... Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, from the first page of the [docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html):

> pip install pycryptodome

Notice it is **not**

> pip install crypto

which is a totally different package.